# i tried to extract tripadvisor hotel reviews

Tags: r

here i tried to extract hotel reviews from tripadvisor website. i got my output but i need one more details i.e., [review picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdBxZ.png)

i need the value ratings and atmosphere and all..

this is the inspection code :

[inspect code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuS6a.png)

this is my code :

```html
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g297584-d4058953-Reviews-Corbyn_s_Delight-Port_Blair_South_Andaman_Island_Andaman_and_Nicobar_Islands.html"

morepglist <-seq(10,47,10)

pickhotel <- url
# get list of urllinks corresponding to different pages

# url link for first search page
urllinkmain=pickhotel
# counter for additional pages
morepg=as.numeric(morepglist)

urllinkpre=paste(strsplit(urllinkmain,"Reviews-")[[1]][1],"Reviews",sep="")
urllinkpost=strsplit(urllinkmain,"Reviews-")[[1]][2]

urllink=rep(NA,length(morepg)+1)

urllink[1]=urllinkmain
for(i in 1:length(morepg)){
  urllink[i+1]=paste(urllinkpre,"-or",morepg[i],"-",urllinkpost,sep="")
}
head(urllink)
REview_Data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:5) {
  reviews <- urllink[i] %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")
  
  usercount <- urllink[i] %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#REVIEWS .memberBadgingNoText")
  
  id <- reviews %>%
    html_node(".quote a") %>%
    html_attr("id")
  
  quote <- reviews %>%
    html_node(".quote span") %>%
    html_text()
  
  value_rating <- reviews %>%
    html_node("li .recommend-answer") %>%
    html_attr("li") %>%
    gsub("ui_bubble_rating bubble_40", "", .) %>%
    gsub("0", "", .) %>%
    as.integer()
  
  
  rating <- reviews %>%
    html_node(".rating span") %>%
    html_attr("class") %>%
    gsub("ui_bubble_rating bubble_", "", .) %>%
    gsub("0", "", .) %>%
    as.integer()
  
  date <- reviews %>%
    html_node(".rating .ratingDate") %>%
    html_attr("title") %>%
    strptime("%d %b %Y") %>%
    as.POSIXct()
  
  review <- reviews %>%
    html_node(".entry .partial_entry") %>%
    html_text()
  webpage <- read_html(urllink[i])
  
  count <- webpage %>%
    html_node(".see_all_count") %>%
    html_text()
  
  things <- webpage %>%
    html_node("span .header_popularity") %>%
    html_text()
  
  Noofcontribution <- usercount %>%
    html_node(".badgetext") %>%
    html_text()
  
  Noofusefulvotes <- usercount %>%
    html_node(".badgetext:last-child") %>%
    html_text()
  Restaurant_Name<-webpage%>%
    html_node(".heading_title")%>%
    html_text()
  REview_Data <- rbind(REview_Data, data.frame(Restaurant_Name,id, quote,value_rating ,rating,date, review,count,things,Noofcontribution,Noofusefulvotes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

REview_Data
write.csv(REview_Data,"F:/R_Studio/Restaurant3.csv")
```

i cant get my output..

i tried my best . but i dont know how to extract the bubble values from that particular place.. and i successfully extracted it fron over all rating using span...

but here i cant..

Comment: Did you try extracting the html element inside li class ```recommend-answer``` ?

Comment: Note that you are encouraging users here to violate TripAdvisor's [Terms of Use](https://tripadvisor.mediaroom.com/us-terms-of-use): _"you agree not to [...] copy any content or information of this Website using any robot, spider, scraper or other automated means [...] without our express written permission;"_. I guess it's also forbidden for tripadvisor.in and noone has a written permission...

Comment: hi @amrrs , yes i want to extract the hrml elements inside li class

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me.

```
write.table(REview_Data, file = "C:/your_path_here/foo.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA,
            qmethod = "double")
```